# Represent a number as a sum of multiple numbers

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

In how many ways a positive number X can be represented as a sum of Y positive integer numbers and how to find them?

Eg 1: 7 (X) can be represented as a sum of 2 (Y) numbers in following way: 
(3+4), (2+5), (1+6).

Eg 2: 7 (X) can be represented as a sum of 3 (Y) numbers in following way: 
(1+1+5), (1+2+4), (1+3+3), (2+2+3).

*What happens when p = 1 [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485159/representing-a-number-as-a-sum-of-k-pth-powers).*

Comment: See whether this helps you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217597/number-of-ways-to-write-n-as-a-sum-of-k-nonnegative-integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A helpful fuction code is available [here](http://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/61122-represented-a-positive-integer-number-as-a-sum-of-multiple-positive-integer-numbers).